# Distributing a YAJSW Application with PID?

Tags: java, yajsw

I am reading through the YAJSW tutorial here:

http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/#mozTocId768274

From what I understand, I need to create a wrapper.conf configuration file for wrapping my Java application.  But in order to create wrapper.conf, I need to call getConfig.bat PID

But if I create this wrapper around my application, then distribute it to someone else, won't 
the PID that I used to create the original wrapper be different from the PID of the application when it runs on the other user's machine?  And if that is the case, then how will the service even run on their machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PID is only for the script `genConfig.bat` to find how you run your application and automatically configure a `wrapper.conf` for you. It's supposed to be a facilitator, but it complicated the process instead.

I recommend you skip that part and try to configure your `wrapper.conf` manually.

Answer (score -1):

You can easiliy obtain the PID for genConfig.bat by opening up the Windows Task Manager and add the PID column via the menus.